# Как создать один обработчик события Click для нескольких кнопок?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

На форме лежит 33 кнопки.

Как не писать для каждой кнопки свой обработчик событий `button_Click`, а создать какой-то единый обработчик, применимый для каждой кнопки?

Comment: привяжите один обработчик события ButtonClick для всех кнопок и все

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: выделяем кнопку на форме, переходим во вкладку Events тут выбираем строку Click и нажимаем на ней два раза мышью - IDE генерирует код обработчика события. Потом выделяем другую кнопку и в строке Click выбираем ранее созданное событие. вот и все

Comment: а как определить в этом обработчике, что нажата какая-то определенная кнопка?

Comment: напишите в обработчике события следующий код:     
Button btn = sender as Button;
MessageBox.Show("Была нажата кнопка " +  btn.Name);

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо. А что такое "sender as"?

Comment: sender - это параметр обработчика события. as - это приведение типа. Рад был помочь!

Comment: используйте `Button btn = (Button)sender;`. Так Вы сразу (а не на следующей строчке) узнаете, что `sender` это не кнопка.

Comment: @NMD оформили бы развернутым ответом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Создаем обработчик события сответствующий необходимому прототипу для обработки события нажатия по контролу (Click):

```
private void CommonBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = ((Button)sender).Text;
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

При загрузке формы производим установку ранее созданного обработчика события для всех кнопок формы(если установка данного обработчика нужна не для всех кнопок, можно добавить дополнительное условие, чтобы решить эту проблему).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in this.Controls) //обходим все элементы формы
    {
        if (item is Button) // проверяем, что это кнопка
        {
            ((Button)item).Click += CommonBtn_Click; //приводим к типу и устанавливаем обработчик события  
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаём своё свойство для кнопки что бы их отличать.

```
class CustomButton: Button
{
    public int CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

И далее в коде...

```
CustomButton[] сustomButton = new CustomButton[33];

private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        сustomButton[i] = new CustomButton();
        customButton[i].CustomProperty = i;
        customButton[i].Click += CustomButton_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(customButton[i]);
    }
}

private void CustomButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = (((CustomButton)sender).CustomProperty.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Comment: Такое кастомное свойство есть уже у любого контрола -- это `Tag`.

Answer (score -1):

Зайдите в дизайнер формы, либо в конструкторе формы после

`InitializeComponent();`

пропишите привязку события необходимых кнопок к 1 методу обработки этого события, например:

```
toolStripButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(toolStripButton1_Click);
```

таким образом обработка события нажатия на кнопку toolStripButton1 будет выполнено в методе toolStripButton1_Click. Событие System.EventHandler ссылается на делегат, а делегат требует определенный шаблон метода (в подсказках VSStudio это все выводится), для данного примера метод обработки события должен принимать 2 параметра (object sender, EventArgs e):

```
void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ваши действия при возникновении события нажатия на кнопку
}
```

Почему `new System.EventHandler`? Потому что такой делегат требуется для события `toolStripButton1.Click`, если почитаете про события то поймете. Для других событий могут требоваться другие делегаты и передаваемые параметры.