# Как обратиться к объекту который присвоит данное событие

Tags: c#, winforms

Вопрос таков: нужно сделать для динамического кол-ва checkBox событие которое будет менять цвет текста на Coral например. Не могу я для каждого свое событие делать это долго и нерационально. Как быть с данным вопросом?

```
    private void changeColor_Tool (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            ForeColor = Color.Coral;
    }
```

Comment: Что мешает подписать все боксы на 1 событие?

Comment: Мне нужно в свойство checked_changed вписать изменение цвета КОНКРЕТНОГО элемента который изменил состояние. Мой код сейчас изменить текст формы.

Comment: Я и так буду приписывать всем только это событие. Но нужно что бы тот кто вызвал событие изменил цвет

Comment: Для этого вы и передаете в событие два значение, sender - объект, который вызвал его и EventArgs - определенные значения этого события. Вот вам и надо работать с sender'ом. Можете глянуть один из моих [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795904/Динамическое-создание-кнопок-и-работа-с-ними-c/795919#795919), там идет создание кнопок динамически, все они подписываются на один обработчик, который удаляет нажатую кнопку. Посмотрите, будет полезно (особенно со строки `var button = (Button)sender;`).

Comment: Вроде понял сейчас попробую, а потом напишите в ответ

Comment: Всё отлично работает только маленький нюанс напишите в ответ те строчки приведение к Button только к CheckBox и с сменой цвета обратно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код для формы с набросанными на ней контролами, привязку события нужно делать тогда когда все контролы будут созданы, здесь я их набросал в дизайнере.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach (CheckBox checkBox in this.Controls)
    {
       checkBox.CheckStateChanged += CheckBoxOnCheckStateChanged;
    }
}

private void CheckBoxOnCheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var senderBox = (CheckBox) sender;
    senderBox.ForeColor = senderBox.Checked ? Color.Coral : Color.Black;
}
```

Comment: Точно так секунду назад с тернарным оператором сделал ^_^

Comment: При тесте полном ваш вариант более без ошибок

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в коде сделать следующее:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            var changeColor = new CheckBox();
            changeColor.CheckedChanged += ChangeColor_CheckedChanged;
          //Добавление на контрол или в коллекцию
        }

private void ChangeColor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
        var havecheck = checkbox.Checked;//Cделал тернарным опертором
        checkbox.ForeColor = havecheck ? Color.Coral : Color.Black;
    }
```

Что происходит в коде?
Мы сначала циклом создаем динамические контролы, добавляем им обработчик, а затем добавляем в нужную коллекцию. Далее в обработчике мы определяем передавший контрол, и изменяем его ForeColor.

Comment: А обратно что бы цвет менял? Как можно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения, начал писать ответ, до вашего комментария.

Comment: Хотя можно с bool сделать

Comment: @AquaGF дополнить else{changeColor.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.white}

Comment: checkbox.ForeColor = havecheck ? Color.Coral : Color.Black;

Comment: Правку нужно что бы приняли

Comment: @VladimirT Да без проблем. Только одно но.. Этот вопрос - [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551994/220553) и его стоило бы закрыть, как дубликат.

Comment: а что за havecheck?

Comment: Да я по моему видел этот вопрос - только там кол-во кнопок определено а у меня нет по этому встал в ступор

Comment: @yolosora правил ответ забыл переменную обьявить

Comment: @yolosora havecheck - переменная типа bool, человек который правил забыл объявить и присвоть значение

Comment: у вас код нерабочий даже если убрать двойное объявление переменной...

Comment: @yolosora поправил, что-бы это было правильно

Comment: @VladimirT осталось удалить двойное объявление переменной)))

Comment: @ AquaGF см предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @yolosora поправил)))